# specific time format for api documenting using flask restplus

Tags: python, swagger, flask-restplus

I have an api which accepts start_time, end_time and a boolean closed_all_day in body of the request.

```
from flask_restplus import Namespace, fields

timings = api.model('open times', {
     'start_time': fields.String(required=True, description='Time in 24 hour HH:MM format, defaulted to 00:00 if closed_all_day'),
     'end_time': fields.String(required=True, description='Time in 24 hour HH:MM format, defaulted to 00:00 if closed_all_day'),
     'closed_all_day': fields.Boolean(required=True, description='If True overwrites start_time and end_time')
})
```

The format of start_time and end_time would be in HH:MM (24 hour format)

if I use

```
fields.Date
```

or

```
fields.DateTime
```

then I got the full ISO date format, which is also not what I want.

Is there a way to restrict the input to HH:MM format ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the way to do it:

```
from datetime import time


class TimeFormat(fields.Raw):
    def format(self, value):
        return time.strftime(value, "%H:%M")

timings = Model('timings', {
    'start_time': TimeFormat(readonly=True, description='Time in HH:MM', default='HH:MM'),
    'end_time': TimeFormat(readonly=True, description='Time in HH:MM', default='HH:MM'),
    'closed_all_day': fields.Boolean(readOnly=True, description='True or False', default=False)
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up creating my own `Time` class inspired by other `DateTime` and `Date` classes

```py
class Time(Raw):
    """
    Return a formatted time string in %H:%M.
    """

    __schema_type__ = "string"
    __schema_format__ = "time"


    def __init__(self, time_format="%H:%M", **kwargs):
        super(Time, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.time_format = time_format


    def format(self, value):
        try:
            value = self.parse(value)
            if self.time_format == "iso":
                return value.isoformat()
            elif self.time_format:
                return value.strftime(self.time_format)
            else:
                raise MarshallingError("Unsupported time format %s" % self.time_format)
        except (AttributeError, ValueError) as e:
            raise MarshallingError(e)

    def parse(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, time):
            return value
        if isinstance(value, str):
            return time.fromisoformat(value)
        else:
            raise ValueError("Unsupported Time format")
```